# Store a bill of materials in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am manipulating some data with Python that consists exclusively of part numbers and their relationship (parent/child) to other parts. The parts are on many levels of the bill of materials (BOM). What is the best way to store this data within Python?

Originally, I used nested dictionaries as shown below with generic part numbers for readability (actual part names are random characters). However, I don't think storing data (part names) as a dictionary key is a good way to do this because it makes retrieving the part names difficult.

```
>>> BOM = {}
>>> BOM['Part 1'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 1']['Part 1.1'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 1']['Part 1.1']['Part 1.1.1'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 1']['Part 1.2'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 1']['Part 1.3'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 2'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 2']['Part 2.1'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 2']['Part 2.2'] = {}
>>> BOM['Part 2']['Part 2.2']['Part 2.2.1'] = {}
>>> print(BOM)

{'Part 1': {'Part 1.1': {'Part 1.1.1': {}}, 'Part 1.2': {}, 'Part 1.3': {}}, 'Part 2': {'Part 2.1': {}, 'Part 2.2': {}, 'Part 2.2.1': {}}}
```

If not nested dictionaries, how should I store the parts? Or should I be using nested dictionaries differently?

Comment: What's difficult about accessing parts that way? Do you mean iterating over them? Or accessing specific parts?

Comment: I'm using values to look up keys when I take a child and try to find the parent. The above is better suited for the opposite, finding children when the parent is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent/child relations usually are stored as trees. [anytree](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/) supports such data structure. This will allow you to retrieve the name of a node easily as well.
If the parts are just numbers which increment by one as in the example, a simple nested list would suffice (then the index and depth of the nested list implies the name of the part number).

Comment: This looks very promising! Thank you. The part numbers do not include their structure, I only used that for this example. They're actually a series of random numbers and letters.

Comment: No problem! If you deem this the correct answer, please mark this answer as correct using the check mark.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Because some parts had multiple parents (not shown in example with the question), I had to be careful how I organized my data. I updated my question with my solution using `anytree`.

Comment: in general BOM is not a tree, since sum-assemblies can share parts. In general, BOM is is a directed graph.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using [anytree](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/)

```
from anytree import Node
bom = {} # dictionary with part as key and list of nodes as value, ex. bom[part] = [Node(part), Node(part), ...]
for (part, parent) in part_list:
    if part not in bom:
        # Create key and initialize value if not in bom
        bom[part] = []
    if parent in bom:
        # Add part to all instances of parent
        for parent_node in bom[parent]:
            bom[part].append(Node(part, parent=parent_node))
    else:
        # If part has no parents, just create the node
        bom[part].append(Node(part))
```

Comment: in general BOM is not a tree, since sum-assemblies can share parts. In general, BOM is is a directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if an element in a dictionary has no value, it would be added as a list within the dictionary. Like:
`{'Part 1': {'Part 1.1': ['Part 1.1.1'], 'Part 1.2': {}, 'Part 1.3': {}}, 'Part 2': ['Part 2.1', 'Part 2.2', 'Part 2.2.1']}`

Comment: I can do that, but I still need to be able to do things such as retrieve parent parts `Part 1` and `Part 1.1` when given `Part 1.1.1`.